# Android Multi-Touch Bug: Max Number of Pointers drops to 2 Randomly

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, multi-touch, samsung-mobile

I track touches in a view via its `OnTouchListener()` in my app but for some reason the max number of pointers the app can detect randomly drops from 10 to 2. The only way I can reproduce the bug is by rapidly tapping the screen with multiple fingers, and even at that it's inconsistent.

I log the pointer id of touches entering and leaving the screen with the code below. The logs track pointers fine for up to 10 simultaneous touches, but when the aformentioned bug occurs the logs only show up to 2 pointer ids active at once.

Is this a hardware glitch of my Galaxy S6 Edge? Is there a way to test why new touches aren't triggering motion events?

```
View.OnTouchListener touch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //check if user flung the screen
            mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);          
            // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
            int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
            // get pointer index from the event object
            int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            // get pointer ID
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

            switch (maskedAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:{
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Pointer down = " + Integer.toString(pointerId));

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    int numberOfPointers = event.getPointerCount();  //fetch number of active pointers
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPointers; i++) {
                        //do stuff
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Pointer cleared = " + Integer.toString(pointerId));

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear from your example, but it seems that

```
return  mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Must be last line(https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Comment: Where do you see a requirement that this must be the last line? I don't see mention of this on the doc you linked.

Comment: After testing it, returning the touch event instead of true breaks my Gesture Detection code.

Comment: no, if you processed event - return true, anything skipped (default) should return  mDetector.onTouchEvent(event); Just add case:

default: return  mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);